# jQuery "load" method does not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display a separate page into a `div` when click on a link which id is "about". for this purpose my html structure is bellow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Budget Rental</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>

</head>

<body>

    <section id="home">



        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-xl-5 leftcontent">

                    <h1>The Latest</h1>
                    <img class="img-responsive box-shadow" src="images/latestcamera.jpg" alt="Camera"/> <br>

                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/image1.jpg" alt="Camera"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/image2.jpg" alt="Camera"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/image3.png" alt="Camera"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="about-placeholder">
                        <a id="about" href="about.html">Read more about our latest product</a>
                    </div>  

                </div>

            </div>          
        </div>


    </section>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

My script is bellow:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#about").click(function(){
        jQuery(".about-placeholder").load("about.html .body-text");
        return false;

    });
});
```

**Problem:** When Use `return false` then its not **loading**. when I remove `return false` then its redirects with another page. I want to show it within this page. What should I do?

Comment: Read the docs, and check the parameters: https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Have you tried adding your jquery in the head?  Everything looks correct, but it shouldn't be redirecting to a new page.  http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp

Comment: `.load` takes either a [URL to load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) or a [function to run](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/), and you've given it a selector. What do you expect/hope will happen?

Comment: About it's an `anchor tag` element...I think that maybe the `jquery` library is not loaded at all..

Comment: I already have read the document. -Mr. Hackerman

Comment: Yeah, I have tried this also. - Mr. oompahlumpa

Comment: Then could you please any suggestion to make it happen? - Mr. apsillers

Comment: @Shihab Just do `.load("about.html")`? Or are you trying only to load the `.body-text` element within the HTML page at `about.html`? If so, `load` is probably not the right tool for you -- or at least, you should `load` it into a non-visible element, extract `.body-text`, and place it in the placeholder.